# iOS push notifications - how to deal with device ID?

Tags: ios, push-notification

What is most commonly used strategy?
I'm trying now to implement following:

On application start:

- Get previously saved device Id from some local storage
- Get device Id
- If changed, save new Id, send update to server

Is this right approach?
What is the best way to store device Id locally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best practice is to send the push device token (not the same as the uniqueIdentifier mentioned by Serg Shiyan) to Apple every time the app starts. This will let Apple know your app is still active.

See registering for remote push notifications:

> By requesting the device token and passing it to the provider every time your application launches, you help to ensure that the provider has the current token for the device.

from the [Local and Push notifications Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2)

In my experience there are a number of reasons why push tokens might be invalidated. These include app deinstalls and mixing apps with different certificates (dev, ad-hoc running against sandbox / live push servers). It will save you some debugging by sending the token on start each time as recommended.

So basically there is no reason to store the push token other than in memory while your app is running. You just request a new one (possibly the same one) the next time your app starts.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing is that I still need some token to pass to the server to identify the user/device and I still need to keep it on device somehow. I guess in user defaults.

Comment: Yes, identifying a user is probably done best using a different mechanism (device tokens, user accounts, etc), stored in the keychain, user defaults or even iCloud. This way you can even have situations where the same user has multiple push tokens registered if he's using the app on multiple devices.

Comment: Looks like the link given above has been updated: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/

Comment: The answer says `send the push device token (not the same as the uniqueIdentifier mentioned by Serg Shiyan) to Apple every time the app starts`-- I think the device token isn't sent to `Apple`, but rather to your own server (or a 3rd party server), which is then using Apple's service to send the notifications.

Answer (score 3):

"An alphanumeric string unique to each device based on various hardware details. (read-only) (Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Instead, create a unique identifier specific to your app.)

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *uniqueIdentifier
```

Special Considerations
Do not use the uniqueIdentifier property. To create a unique identifier specific to your app, you can call the `CFUUIDCreate` function to create a UUID, and write it to the defaults database using the `NSUserDefaults` class." (Apple Inc)